# UVM DPI-C function import

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, system-verilog-dpi

Can somebody please educate me why we need DPI-C function import to do UVM specific functions like `uvm_hdl_force` or `uvm_hdl_deposit` even when force and deposit system verilog constructs exist? What extra flexibility does the C functions give with these regards?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's no **deposit** functionality in SystemVerilog, only **force**. Although most tools give you deposit functionality, there is no standard way to deal with it. The DPI-C give you a tool independent method.
- UVM REG gives you the ability to look-up registers by string name, and build paths from string hierarchies. Although there are ways of creating this functionality without resorting to the DPI/VPI, it's far easier to use the VPI.
- If your DUT is VHDL, there is no standard for interoperability between standards with hierarchical references across language boundaries.